# how to put a form inside a table in CSS

Tags: css

I am making a website for blog. The problem is that I am making a signup box and I have put a form inside a table.But now I am not able to enter data in the id and password fields.
How do I position the elements so that my problem is solved?

**CSS** *(inside HTML / Head / Style elements)*

```css
#l1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:600px;
}
#tx1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:305px;
    left:672px;
}
#l2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:345px;
    left:600px;
}
#tx2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:358px;
    left:672px;
}
#tab {
    position:absolute;
    top:235;
    left:570;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #777;
}
.e {
    color:#EE6AA7;
    font-family:Helevetica;
    font-size:17px;
}
```

**HTML** *(inside HMTL / Body elements)*

```html
<form>
    <table border="1" id="tab" width="320" height="215">
        <tr>
            <p id="l1" class="e">Id</p>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="tx1" class="e1">
            <br>
            <p id="l2" class="e">Password</p>
            <input type="text" name="pswrd" id="tx2" class="e1">
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute;` everywhere?

Comment: "Helevetica"? Try "Helvetica" :p

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, the only elements that can be a child of a `tr` are `td` and `th` elements. See: [`<table>` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Comment: ...you need to figure out the TABLE part first, it seems.

Comment: off topic: while your at it, try to use real class names, not some cryptic code that will cause you a lot of headache if you ever have to change something

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that you're trying to use position absolute everywhere. Actually if you want to place your form using absolute position do it only for ONE main block. And place inputs inside this block without absolute position. Also there are some issues with your code, especially about table (no  elements)

So, try to make a div with absolute position somewhere on the page, and inside this div put your table.

Something like http://dabblet.com/gist/6615265